# when to use a definite article with abstract nouns

Tags: article

So here are two sentences:

> Ich habe Angst

> Es gibt keinen Grund zur Angst

I'm just wondering what the underlying framework for leaving "Angst" without a definite article in the first sentence while using it in the second is.

Comment: Bei solchen Beispielsätzen kann man es schon mit der Angst zu tun bekommen ...

Answer (score 1):

There are certain types of specific fears. e.g. *arachnophobia* is the fear of spiders, *agoraphobia* the fear of wide open places, etc.. But

> Ich habe Angst.

is about a feeling - the fear itself - rather than a specific reason for having it. It is a *condition*, not an *action*. There is an equivalent in English but it works different:

> I am frightened.

Here *one is* something, in German *one has* something. It would be possible to say (grammatically correct but unidiomatic):

> Ich bin angsterfüllt.

but it would sound strange the same way

> I have fear.

would sound strange. Conditions and actions are expressed differently and they are expressed differently in German and English.

In the second sentence the quality of "Angst" as a condition takes a backseat and the feeling is more treated like an *action*. Consider the following variants:

> Es gibt keinen Grund zur Angst|Unruhe|Eile|Pünktlichkeit|Aufgabe.

"Angst" and "Unruhe" (restlessness) are arguably feelings, but "Eile" (rush), "Pünktlichkeit" (being on time) or "Aufgabe" (resignation) aren't. Still they fit the sentence, because they are all *nouns describing actions*.

Notice that the need for the *Artikel* vanishes once the "action-quality" of the expression is taken away:

> Es gibt keinen Grund zur Angst.
> Es gibt keinen Grund, Angst zu haben.

Answer (score -1):

It's the case. You can't leave out the article in dative and genitive case.

Comment: That is quite wrong. "Mit Angst kommst du hier nicht weiter." or "Wegen Überfüllung geschlossen" are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @KilianFoth Have any clue what this could be ascribed to instead?